# Assistance with rsync hourly/daily/weekly backup snapshot script

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

I've been using a modified version of the [rsync snapshot script from Mike Rubel](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/) and have been having some issues tweaking it to do what I'd like. His only takes hourly snapshots; I'm hoping for snapshots every hour, day, week, and month via crontab.

Here's my hourly script:

```
if [ -d $BUP/temp ] ; then
   rm -rf $BUP/temp ;
fi;

rsync -avzO  --delete --exclude-from=$CONFIG/rsync-excludes /home/jwhendy/ $DAT/jwhendy/ ;
rsync -avzO  --delete --exclude=vault* --link-dest=../vault.hourly.0 $DAT/ $BUP/temp ;

if [ -d $BUP/vault.hourly.2 ] ; then    
   rm -rf $BUP/vault.hourly.2 ;
fi;

if [ -d $BUP/vault.hourly.1 ] ; then
   mv $BUP/vault.hourly.1 $BUP/vault.hourly.2 ;
fi;

if [ -d $BUP/vault.hourly.0 ] ; then
   mv $BUP/vault.hourly.0 $BUP/vault.hourly.1 ;
fi;

mv $BUP/temp $BUP/vault.hourly.0 ;
```

Here's the daily script (weekly/monthly ones are pretty much the same):

```
if [ -d $BUP/vault.daily.2 ] ; then    
    rm -rf $BUP/vault.daily.2 ;
fi;

if [ -d $BUP/vault.daily.1 ] ; then
    mv $BUP/vault.daily.1 $BUP/vault.daily.2 ;
fi;

if [ -d $BUP/vault.daily.0 ] ; then
    mv $BUP/vault.daily.0 $BUP/vault.daily.1 ;
fi;

if [ -d $BUP/vault.hourly.2 ] ; then
    cp -al $BUP/vault.hourly.2 $BUP/vault.daily.0 ;
fi;
```

The hourly script works great. What I'm struggling with is the transition from hourly -> daily (and daily -> weekly, etc.).

At present, the script will function like this, say, if the hourly script runs 6x in a day and the daily script runs after that ("hourly.n" is abbreviated "hr.n" and "b_m" stands for an individual snapshot):

```
| hour 1     | hour 2     | hour 3     | hour 4     | hour 5     | end of day    |
|------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------|
| hr.0 (b_0) | hr.0 (b_1) | hr.0 (b_2) | hr.0 (b_3) | hr.0 (b_4) | hr.0 (b_5)    |
|            | hr.1 (b_0) | hr.1 (b_1) | hr.1 (b_2) | hr.1 (b_3) | hr.1 (b_4)    |
|            |            | hr.2 (b_0) | hr.2 (b_1) | hr.2 (b_2) | hr.2 (b_3)    |
|            |            |            |            |            | daily.0 (b_3) |
```

Since hourly.sh zaps hourly.2 if it exists, we can see that daily.0 is created for the first time with b_3 and I've lost b_0, b_1, and b_2. I'd prefer to do an incremental dump of hourly.2 into daily.0 every hour, prior to removing it. That way, at any given time I'll have hourly.0, 1 and  2, and daily.0 will contain the latest version of hourly.2 before it was deleted.

Hopefully that makes sense.

I've tried taking the `cp -al $BUP/hourly.2 $BUP/daily.0 ;` line and putting it in the hourly script. There are three problems I've run into with this:

- it seems to take a lot longer than the rsync script alone, even though it's *technically* just copying some hardlinks
- since these are hardlinks, the first backup will be the full size (~20GB) in my case; the subsequent runs should produce snapshots the size of updated files (which it does). I would expect the largest snapshot to progressively move further and further back in the tree (eventually at monthly.2). This `cp -al` line seems to be holding it steady at daily.0 and it never moves back to daily.1 and so on (this could be a misunderstanding of how `du` works.
- I can't figure out how not to break the chain of backups, which forces a new snapshot (full 20GB) to have to be recreated. In other words, hourly.2 keeps dumping into daily.0... but eventually `mv $BUP/daily.0 $BUP/daily.1` will make daily.0 no longer exist. Thus, it will have to be recreated from scratch the next time hourly.sh runs.

In any case, hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to accomplish. I'd like assistance for transitioning each script (hourly, daily, weekly) into the next "bucket" (daily, weekly, monthly) without having to break the hardlink chain.

I'd also like not to lose significant snapshots along the way as shown in the table above.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: For your second problem: How do you mean, the largest snapshot moves back? As far as I know your first backup and all the following backups should be "equivalent". A hardlinked file doesn't care which link existed first. Do you get different sizes for the first and the incremental backups when checking the size with du? (Assuming you didn't change much between the backups...)

Comment: @JanRüegg: I get different results with `du`. I typically do `du -sh /media/bup/vault.*`. One of them always shows up ~20GB and (assuming the script wasn't interrupted) the rest are anywhere from 10s to 100s of megabytes depending on what changed. I sometimes see more than one in the 20GB range, and so I figured the hard link chains were being broken... perhaps I just don't understand how `du` measures the sizes? Will it ever "double count," or should I be using du on the total folder vs. having it iterate through all snapshots?

Comment: @Hendy: Usually there is no such thing as a hardlink "chain", but all the files just link to the same data on the harddrive. And that also means, that a "du" on a single one of them should give the full size, but doing a "du" on all of them will not double-count. (Thats at least how it is for me, after a quick test... do you have a special filesystem or something like that?)

Comment: @JanRüegg: no special filesystem, and that's how mine behaves... which is why I think something's not right in my transition from hourly.2 -> daily.0... because there seems to be two sets of very large snapshots. I'll try again and verify as I've been tinkering with the script a bit. I may just try rsnapshot as suggested above, though it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I made a test about the hardlinks, here is what happens for me:

```
➜  rsync -az0 /home/jan/tmp/Source /home/jan/tmp/Dir1
➜  rsync -az0 /home/jan/tmp/Source /home/jan/tmp/Dir2 --link-dest=/home/jan/tmp/Dir1
➜  du -hs /home/jan/tmp/Source
124M    /home/jan/tmp/Source
➜  du -hs /home/jan/tmp/Dir1
124M    /home/jan/tmp/Dir1
➜  du -hs /home/jan/tmp/Dir2
124M    /home/jan/tmp/Dir2
```

You can see that all the hardlinks to files are indeed equivalent. That means, in itself, every one of the backups is a "full" backup, giving you the full filesize if you do a "du" only on that one.

```
➜  du -hs /home/jan/tmp/Dir1 /home/jan/tmp/Dir2
124M    /home/jan/tmp/Dir1
0   /home/jan/tmp/Dir2
```

However, if you do a "du" on all of them (like in the 6th command above), it will recognize the hardlinks and show you a "zero" size for all the hardlinks it has encountered before. However, this only depends on the ordering of the arguments, and not on which hardlink was "first":

```
➜  du -hs /home/jan/tmp/Dir2 /home/jan/tmp/Dir1
124M    /home/jan/tmp/Dir2
0   /home/jan/tmp/Dir1
```

To your actual problem:

Instead of doing a `cp -al $BUP/hourly.2 $BUP/daily.0` and then deleting hourly.2 anyway, couldn't you just do a `mv $BUP/hourly.2 $BUP/daily.0`, what will be *much* faster?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation concerning `du`. That's very helpful. Yes, `mv` would be faster, and in hindsight, does what I was intending to do with my `cp -al` command (I was thinking about things incorrectly in choosing `cp` over `mv`). I still haven't solved the issue of losing x number of hourly snapshots by the time daily runs, but perhaps I just need to do more hourly snapshots to make up for this. Thanks again for the help. Perhaps my question was founded mostly on a misunderstanding of hardlinks and `du`.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. In that case, could you mark the problem as solved by accepting the answer?

Comment: Sorry. I actually meant to when I read it, but it was within three minutes so I had to wait... and then totally forgot :)